# How to distinguish between virtual disk image formats?

Tags: virtualization, images, vdi, qcow2, vmdk

There is huge number of different formats for virtual storage files for desktop and server purposes (vmdk, qcow2, vdi, vdk, etc.). I'm writing a little script for manipulating them and would like the script to be able to distinguish between them.

Of course, it can be done via extension, but I want this to be more reliable. I tried commands **file** or **qemu-img**, but the results are not quite clear. Any idea improving my methods?

Comment: Why are the results not clear - what are the results? Which file-version?

Comment: Well.. I had strange results yesterday, because for .vmdk od .vdi qemu-img info gave me "raw". Since I created new different versions from original qcow2 and ran qemu-img info again, everthing looks just fine, even when I rewrite the extension of vmdk to vdi, it recognizes it. Thx for having me retry this..

Comment: Perhaps `file` gave you "raw" while `qemu-img info` gave the right results? The file-command looks into the first few bytes and checks them against a regex in its "database". On Linux the file-extension does not matter much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`qemu-img info` should be able to recognize all the formats QEMU understands. Unfortunately, even with the formats QEMU supports, the proprietary vendors change the format, so qemu-img can't always use them

Comment: Yes, qemu-img info is great way to do that.. Thanks..